# Using server IP in PAM LDAP query

Tags: ldap, pam

In our company we have a lot of servers (at this moment arount 20, numbers increasing). Not all LDAP users are allowed to get access to the same servers.

My Idea is to make one user group per server and use somehow the IP address of the server to check if the use is allowed to log in.

How can I configure this using pam?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to bind it to the ip address of the server, but here's a way to bind the server to a group.

I'd recommend using pam_access if your distribution makes it easy (e.g. RHEL / Fedora have `authconfig --enablepamaccess`). You'd then modify `/etc/security/access.conf` to have a line similar to:

```
- : ALL EXCEPT root (groupname) : ALL
```

`root` is important because this line will also restrict console login. That's just for starters. You can get more complex, like using multiple lines to describe who can log in from where, see `man 5 access.conf`, though this may be sufficient for your needs.

---

You can do something similar for just ssh using `AllowGroups` in your sshd_config.